# template Base Class initialization

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, initialization

while in visual c++ the code below is accepted, g++ will generate the error:
"class Derived does not have any field name Base"
which is following the standard?

```
template <class T>
class Base
{
public:
    Base(){};
};

template <class T>
class Derived:public Base<T>
{
public:
    Derived():Base(){}
};
```

BTW: both accept

```
Derived():Base<T>(){}
```

so meantime, I will follow gcc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MSVC++ is not correct. `Base` is a template, not a type.

Note that in the usual case, `Base` is looked up in the scope of `Derived<T>`, which means that it will first find the injected class name inherited from `Base<T>`, which refers to the type `Base<T>`. But as you have a dependent base class, the name inherited from `Base<T>` is not found (the base class scope is not looked into).