# No template argument needed for initialization of base class which is a template instance?

Tags: c++, templates, initialization, base-class

I have a non-template class which is derived from a specific template instance. As usual, the base class must be initialized in the derived class's constructor. I discovered that it is possible to omit the specific template argument when calling the constructor: The major compilers (VC, g++, clang) accept it. That looks strange because the class template in itself is not a class name:

```bash
$ cat template-base.cpp && g++ --pedantic -o template-base template-base.cpp  && ./template-base
```

```cpp
template <int I>
struct T
{
        T(int) {}
};

struct DT: public T<1>
{
        // Note: T<1>(42) is possible but not necessary.
        // T<2>(42) is an error ("T<2> is not a base class", which is correct).
        DT(): T(42) {}
};

int main()
{
        DT dt;
}
```

(There is [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5860783/3150802) answered by Johannes Schaub, in which also the derived class itself is a template. In that case the template argument is mandatory, even though it is equally well deductible there.)

Why can I use a template name like a class name here? `T` is not a class!

Answer (score 7):

This has to do with the [injected class name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name).  When a class template is used as a base class, the language allows you to use the name of the template as if you specified the parameters since it knows what those parameters are.  Doing

```
DT(): T(42) {}
```

gets expanded to

```
DT(): T<1>(42) {}
```

by the compiler for you.

---

The standard language that allows this can be found in [[temp.local]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.local)

Comment: _"When a class template is used as a base class"_ sounds a bit iffy. The injected class name isn't special cased for base classes, it is found by name lookup in the base class after `T` couldn't be found in the derived class. This is pertinent in the case where the base class is a dependent type, or when there is a member `T` in the derived class.